# Application object access from regular class in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Our teachers (coaches for this project) suggested to store our DAO objects in the Application object, so there's one object of each available for the whole application.

This Application object is easily accessed in the Page codebehind itself, but how do we access it from a plain class that is not extending anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For code in classes, you can use `HttpContext.Current.Application`, for which you need to import the `System.Web` namespace.

Comment: Thank you, did not know it would be this easy :)